# Fritz!Box cannot use mailserver that uses ECDSA X.509-certificate

Tags: email, ssl, certificate, fritzbox

My **Fritz!Box 6590** using current **Fritz!OS 7.12** cannot use my mail server to send out push service notifications. The problem is, that my mail server uses **ECDSA certificates**. I see in the TLS client hello message from the Fritz!Box that only RSA certificates are supported, neither DSA nor ECDSA certificates are accepted by Fritz!Box. So the mailserver is correctly rejecting the TLS handshake with “no shared cipher”.

[image: TLS handshake capture]

```
postfix/smtpd[22491]: SSL_accept error from unknown[xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]: -1
postfix/smtpd[22491]: warning: TLS library problem: error:1417A0C1:SSL routines:tls_post_process_client_hello:no shared cipher:ssl/statem/statem_srvr.c:2259:
postfix/smtpd[22491]: lost connection after STARTTLS from unknown[xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]
```

Is there any way to enable support for ECDSA certificates in the Fritz!Box? I mean actually there aren't that uncommon, it's a standard type of TLS certificate.

Is there any reason why Fritz!Box shouldn't support this type of certificates?

Comment: “I mean actually there aren't that uncommon, it's a standard type of TLS certificate.” – Not uncommon? Well, I guess that’s one way to describe “super rare”. I have *never* seen this exchange used before. DSA certificates are already extremely rare.

Comment: @DanielB: DSA certificates are rare because it offers no advantages over RSA, only disadvantages. ECDSA certificates are much less rare due to ECC allowing for smaller keys and faster signing on the server side. (But nearly all servers using ECDSA will also have a RSA certificate precisely because of incompatible clients like OP's.)

Comment: In my case I could change the server certificate, because it's mine. But that wouldn't work for the average user, so I think the certificate should be supported.

Comment: @grawity The reason why I chose to use ECDSA instead (and not in addition) of RSA is that it ensures, that a configuration error cannot by accident enable ciphers, that don't provide perfect forward secrecy. DSA and ECDSA always have to use a DH key exchange as the algorithm itself only supports signing.

Comment: @MatthiasWimmer: interesting in depth strategy to ensure proper encryption. And I think too that ECDSA certificates should be supported.

Comment: @MatthiasWimmer: Does that actually prevent you from accidentally enabling ECDH_ECDSA and using the ECDSA cert as if it were an ECDH cert?

Comment: @grawity I'm not completely sure whether I understand your question correctly. Do you mean something like ElGamal I know from GnuPG? Is there some TLS cipher in TLS that would use a static key when using a (EC)DSA key? I had the impression that all cipher suites in TLS that use (EC)DSA keys when implemented “correctly” would do a DH key exchange generating a new key every time.

Comment: As far as I know, there are "ephemeral" ECDHE_* ciphersuites where the server uses a new DH keypair every time, and there are "static" ECDH_* ciphersuites where the server always uses the same DH keypair from its certificate. As far as I know, in the latter, there is no fundamental difference between ECDH certificates and ECDSA certificates – they use the same curves and other parameters, with only the 'keyUsage' bits possibly deciding which way the cert can be used.

Comment: @grawity I think you are talking about the situation, that a fixed `dhparams.pem` file is used on the server. In that case the prime p and the generator g is fixed (that's the two values present in this file). But AFAIK these two parameters are transmitted in clear by TLS anyway. The server still uses a different secret integer a with every key exchange (at least it should). So there could be an implementation error in the TLS stack, but this should not be caused by a configuration error. – And it would affect all ciphers that should normally provide PFS.

Comment: No, I'm not talking about that – dhparams.pem is for 'traditional' DH, we're talking about ECDH.

Comment: @grawity Indeed in the case of ECDH the parameters don't come from `dhparams.pem` but are fixed completely by the curve that is already selected by the cipher. Anyway both sides pick a random number (often called d for ECDH) with each key exchange. Using the same d for several key exchanges would be an implementation error.

Comment: According to https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4492, that's true for `ECDHE` TLS ciphersuites but not for the `ECDH` ones. For the latter, "the server's certificate contains all the necessary keying information", and the client uses "the same curve as the server's _long-term_ public key". (And yes, these ciphersuites are declared obsolete, but that doesn't help with against accidental misconfiguration.)

Comment: @grawity Good catch. Thanks. I have to further go down on this. Anyway it seems to me that OpenSSL 1.1.1d does not even support them. So I see the risk having them enabled by accident a lot lower that forgetting to disable some ciphers that are enabled by default, e.g. because the location of the config file or the configuration key word changes and defaults are used without my knowledge. I see this only as one small building block in getting a more secure mail communications. Having these ECDH ciphers with properties I wasn't aware of proves me that I cannot trust only one layer of security.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way to enable support for DSA certificates in the Fritz!Box? I mean actually there aren't that uncommon, it's a standard type of TLS certificate.

There is no option for this. I think it would not also make any sense to actually support ECDSA certificate but have this support disabled by default.

> Is there any reason why Fritz!Box shouldn't support this type of certificates?

I can think of no sane reason. But note that Fritz!Box is a commercial closed source product so it is impossible to tell what the real reason is. Please [contact the vendor](https://avm.de/service/supportanfrage/support/FRITZ-Box-6590-Cable/de/129/) to get an answer and maybe an improvement in the future.

Comment: I'd like to contact them … but I cannot reach their web server, but I always get a “The connection has timed out” when trying to browse them.
– Oh … it works after disabling Tor. It seems they are blocking connections from the Tor network.